# How to create an inline formset for a reverse foreign key relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I have a Property Model as follows =

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Apartment')
    specifications = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Basic')
    built_up_area = models.FloatField(max_length=6, null=False, default=0)
    total_area = models.FloatField(null=False, default=0)
    number_of_bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_parking_spaces = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0)
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    connectivity = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    neighborhood_quality = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None,
                                            null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')
    state = models.ForeignKey('State')
    pin_code = models.ForeignKey('PinCode')
    developer = models.ForeignKey('Developer', null=True, default=None)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', null=True, default=None)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('custom_user.User')

    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.property_type

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'
```

And a City model as follows -

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(City, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I want to make a single form where I can enter the Property details and while entering the city, I can enter the name of the city instead of selecting from the dropdown list.

So how do I create the inline formset using the inlineformset_factory to create the form?

==EDIT==

I've tried to use the following code to create the formset

```
CityFormset = inlineformset_factory(City, Property,
                                       fields=('city',),
                                       extra=0,
                                       min_num=1,
                                       can_delete=False)
```

Comment: This seems to be the exact use case for inlineformset_factory. What issues are you having?

Comment: well inlineformset_factory seems to work fine if the City model had a fk to the PropertyModel but not the other way round.

Comment: Please do not hassle me for help after only 20 minutes. I have many calls on my time, and contribute to StackOverflow when I can. It is not at all unusual to have to wait a few hours to get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood what an inline formset is. It's for editing the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship: that is, given a parent model of City, you could edit inline the various Properties that belong to that city.

You don't want a formset at all to simply edit the single City that a property can belong to. Instead, override the `city` field within your Property form to be a TextField, and either create a new City or find an existing one in the `clean_city` method.

```
class PropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.TextField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        exclude = ('city',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and not self.data:
            self.initial['city'] = self.instance.city.name

    def save(self, commit=True):
        city_name = self.cleaned_data['city']
        city, _ = City.objects.get_or_create(name=city_name)
        instance = self.save(commit=False)
        instance.city = city
        if commit = True:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: I'm getting the following form validation error 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'

Comment: You need to exclude the existing city field from the form. I've updated the code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks Daniel, this clarified a lot for me. Unfortunately it didn't work for me even though I have a similar requirement. Here is my code if you please have a look at it if you get a chance. I have highlighted the errors I received on this; https://dpaste.de/Gkcy#L65,78,79,86,94

Comment: the above didn't work for me and I had a nightmare working this out but finally got the answer. here it is; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907731/django-overriding-save-on-inline-formset/31908406#31908406

Comment: That first paragraph should be in the documentation about inline formsets. Tough it seems obvious after you get the concept it is hard to understand how to deal with foreignkeys on the "one" side.