# Inline Formset Foreign Key as text Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I need to do something very similar to the following SO question;
[How to create an inline formset for a reverse foreign key relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245022/how-to-create-an-inline-formset-for-a-reverse-foreign-key-relationship)

Although there is a solution on this but it does not work for me.

When I implement this solution I get the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error and save method runs a infinite loop.

Here is my code;
https://dpaste.de/Gkcy#L65,78,79,86,94

I have highlighted the code where I receive the errors.

Can anyone look into this please, this has been bothering me for many days now and yes, I am new to this :(