# Django overriding Save on inline formset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I am now zombified and am waiting for someone to hit me and put me to sleep. I know this is simple and since I am new to django and to python I am doing it wrong.

I wanted a model FK field to be rendered as a text field..easy peasy (not the linux OS)....right?

I don't think so...

well, I got one solution on SO [reverse foreign key relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245022/how-to-create-an-inline-formset-for-a-reverse-foreign-key-relationship)

but alas it did not work for me and I tried and tried and treid...and so on...

I place my code here and if anyone for sake of all that is holy or evil can help me out on this and additionally if possible provide some documentation so I can learn how to do these things by myself in future (also teach me how to catch the fish)...I would be greatly thankful and the lord will shower his/her blessing upon you.

**models.py**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ''' Add/update recipes. User and Guests can update the recipes.
    Requires admin approval for posting recipes unless user is 
    has some privileges. '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Recipe|title'))
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Recipe|summary'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Recipe|description'))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    prep_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    sources = models.ManyToManyField(Source, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    serving_string = models.ForeignKey(ServingString, null=True, blank=True)
    serving_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    DIFFICULTY = Choices((0, 'easy', 'Easy'), (1, 'medium', 'Medium'), (3, 'hard', 'Hard'))
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY)
    tag = TaggableManager(help_text="A comma separated list of tags")

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Ingredient|amount'))
    amountMax = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, null=True, blank=True)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)
    prep_method = models.ForeignKey(PrepMethod, null=True, blank=True)
    order_index = PositionField(blank=True, null=True, unique_for_field="direction")
    direction = models.ForeignKey(Direction, related_name='ingredients', null=True, blank=True)


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('Food|name'))
    name_sorted = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='', verbose_name=_('Food|name_sorted'))
    group = models.ForeignKey(FoodGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    conversion_src_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
    conversion_factor = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    name_plural = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
    in_foodguide = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title', 'summary', 'description', 'prep_time', 'sources',
                 'category','serving_string', 'serving_value','difficulty', 'tag']

class DirectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Direction
        fields = ['text', ]


class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        exclude = ['name', 'name_sorted', 'group', 'conversion_src_unit', 
                    'conversion_factor', 'name_plural', 'detail', 'in_foodguide']

class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    food_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model =  Ingredient
        # fields = ['amount', 'amountMax', 'unit', 'prep_method', 'food_name']
        exclude = ('food',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'instance', self.instance
        if self.instance and not self.data:
            try:
                self.initial['food_name'] = self.instance.food.name
                # I added the try block else it RelatedObjectDOesNotExist Error occured.
                # Ingredient has no food
            except:
                pass

    def save(self, commit=True):
        food_name =  self.cleaned_data['food_name']
        name, _ = Food.objects.get_or_create(name=food_name)
                # I printed self.save and it goes into infinite loop.
        instance = self.save(commit=False)
        instance.name = name
        if commit == True:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

**forms.py - defined inline formset**

```
DirInline = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Direction, form=DirectionForm, extra=1)
IngInline = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Ingredient, form=IngredientForm, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def submit_recipe(request):
    recipe_form = RecipeForm()
    dir_formset = DirInline(instance=Recipe())
    ing_formset = IngInline(instance=Recipe())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recipe_form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None)
        if recipe_form.is_valid():
            recipe = recipe_form.save(commit=False)
            dir_formset = DirInline(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=recipe)
            ing_formset = IngInline(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=recipe)
            if dir_formset.is_valid() and ing_formset.is_valid():
                recipe.save()
                dir_formset.save()
                ing_formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('submit_recipe'))
            else:
                return render(request, 'recipes-orig/submit_recipe.html', 
                                        {'recipe_form':recipe_form,
                                          'dir_formset':dir_formset,
                                          'ing_formset':ing_formset})


    return render(request, 'recipes-orig/submit_recipe.html', 
                                        {'recipe_form':recipe_form,
                                          'dir_formset':dir_formset,
                                          'ing_formset':ing_formset
                                        })
```

**if you feel it is lengthy code to digest quickly I will make a simple version**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet Potatoes!! I knew I was doing something dumb..it turns out I should have called super in save which I was not...here is the code...but please refer me to some documentation if you can.

**forms.py**

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    food_name =  self.cleaned_data['food_name']
    name, _ = Food.objects.get_or_create(name=food_name)
    instance = super(IngredientForm, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.food = name
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```